# Multiple Servers, Networking Issues

Tags: networking, router, webserver

I have couple of servers, both of which are running different websites. They both have the same external IP address (I'm running them from my home and I have only one router with one IP address).

Those two servers require the same ports. Let's suppose the port is port 80 (HTTP). So I opened port 80 for the first server, but what about the second one?

So now the question is, how can I connect to the right server when they both have the same IP and the same port?

Should I have two routers in my home with two diffrent IPs? What if I had fifty servers, should I get fifty IPs?

Comment: Why not run both websites from the same server?

Comment: You need a reverse proxy. Look up nginx reverse proxy. Requests all come in to the proxy and the proxy distributed the requests to the proper server based on the hostname or URL of the request.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I connect to the right server when they both have the same IP and the same port?

You will need to choose a server to receive all your incoming requests on e.g. port 80 and then set up it up as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (likely through your web server software, such as Apache or Nginx).

What this means is that assuming Server 1 (your "reverse proxy") holds Website A
and Server 2 holds Website B:

- Requests for Website A will be handled by Server 1 directly.
- Requests for Website B (on Server 2) will be passed from Server 1 to Server 2.
- Any response from Server 2 will be passed to Server 1, then back to the client.

In other words, in terms of communication, you would have:

```
Internet <---> Server 1 <---> Server 2
```

And while "website" is used here for general example, there are many types of services that can be relayed this way by a reverse proxy.

The basic steps to setup this kind of communication would be:

1. Port forward incoming requests from your router to Server 1 (Website A).
2. Configure the web server software on Server 1 to send requests for Server 2 (Website B) to the LAN network IP of Server 2.

> What if I had fifty servers, should I get fifty IPs?

Your reverse proxy (e.g. Server 1) can be configured to relay messages to multiple individual servers, based on the request(s) it receives. Note however, that for simplicity, every physical server should ideally be on the same network as your reverse proxy.

Alternatively, if you are just hosting simple websites, the software for most web servers allow more than one website to be hosted on the same port on the same server. For example, in Apache these are known as "virtual hosts" and in Nginx (virtual) "server blocks".

Note that these "virtual servers" also typically form the basis of processing requests via reverse proxy.